# Función JQuery sólo se ejecuta la primera vez

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, mvc

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una página en la cual se crea una tabla mediante un foreach que recoge valores almacenados en las BBDD y los muestra (El lenguaje utilizado es C# y el modelo MVC). Mi intención era crear dos Html.DropDownList dinámicos para hacer un filtro de selección pasándole una función JQuery y que éste, dependiendo de los valores recogidos en los Select, borre la lista creada y cree una nueva sólo con la información que necesito.

¿El problema? El código funciona la primera vez que ejecuto la página, pero al volver atrás y recargar no se realiza de nuevo y me devuelve un error 404 del servidor.

Estos son los DropDownList junto con el botón que valida los resultados:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Crear Nuevo", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
        @Html.DropDownList("Valor1", new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.Valor1).Distinct(), "Valor1", "Nombre"), "Selecciona valores", new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
        @Html.DropDownList("Valor2", new SelectList(Model.Select(i => i.Valor2).Distinct(), "Valor2", "ID"), "Selecciona valores" ,new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
<button id="validacion" type="button" onclick="funcion2();">Validar</button>
```

Y aquí la función JQuery que controla los eventos:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(funcion1());

function funcion1() {
    $("#valor1").on("change",function () {
        $.get("GetValues", { Valor1: $("#valor1").val() }, function (data) {
            if (!$("#valor1").val() == "") {
                $("#valor2").empty();
                $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                    $("#valor2").append("<option value='" + row.recibido1 + "'>" + row.recibido1 + "</option>")

                });
                if (data.length == 0) {
                    $("#valor2").append("<option value=''>No tiene valores</option>");

                }
            }
            else {
                $("#valor2").empty();
                $("#valor2").append("<option value=''>Selecciona valor</option>");

            };
        });
    });
};

function funcion2() {
    $("#validacion").click(function () {
        $.get("GetValues2", { Valor1: $("#valor1").val(), Valor2: $("#valor2").val() }, function (data) {

            $('.valortabla').remove();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#tabla").append("<tr class='valortabla'><td>" + row.recibido1 + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + row.recibido2 + "</td><td>" + row.recibido3 + "</td></tr>");
            });

        });
    });
}
```

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el error? He pensado en problema de caché, he probado con eventos de window.onload, addEventListener y demás y no consigo encontrar la manera para que funcione siempre.

Comment: Si pudieras ser un poco más específico lo agradecería. También he probado sin el document.ready e incluso pasándolo como función anónima de éste, pero en ninguno de los casos me funciona del todo bien (en el primer caso, de hecho, no funciona).

Comment: Pero es que justamente le estoy pasando la función "función1" que está definida más adelante, por lo que no veo error ahí. De hecho de la manera que comentas creando el $(document).ready(function(){ (pasarle aquí la función directamente) } no funciona ni la primera vez. Es extraño y me siento un poco impotente ya xD

Comment: El Ajax te regresa el 404 o toda la página ? En caso de ser el ajax fijate en el apartado de red a que url esta haciendo la petición la primera vez que funciona de forma correcta y a que url le pide la segunda vez que te regresa el 404

Comment: No uso Ajax para hacer las llamadas porque el proyecto en el que estoy inmerso ya usa bastantes tipos de lenguaje distintos y, en principio, me gustaría hacerlo sin añadir más (por el tema del mantenimiento de ésta, que no lo llevaré yo), aunque si no hay más opción lo incluiré. El link que me devuelve es la ruta relativa a la parte del Controlador donde está definido el Json Result, y en principio es el mismo tanto cuando funciona bien como cuando no. ¿Podría ser algo relacionado con trabajar en local?

Comment: Si usas Ajax en ésta parte `$.get("GetValues", { Valor1: $("#valor1").val() }...` La url de la peticción que pones es `"GetValues" ` posiblemente se esta formando mal cuando regresas y recargas ya que no estas poniendo una url completa solo una parte y esta se combina con la que tienes en el request.

Comment: Estoy probando ahora con la función Ajax finalmente. En principio "GetValues" es un método dell Controller y nunca debería cambiar, por lo que creo que ahí no estaría el fallo aunque lo comprobaré de todas formas. El problema que me da ajax es el siguiente: tengo puesto como data { Valor1: $("#valor1").val() }, pero a la hora de crear la URL me añade un &_XXXXXXXX (número que no sé si es aleatorio).

Comment: Tenías razón, compañero, era la Url que no se creaba correctamente. La primera vez que entraba me creaba localhost:XXX/Resultados/GetValues pero las siguientes sólo añadía el GetValues y despreciaba Resultados. Ahora he añadido el paso intermedio directamente en el Get y funciona perfecto.

Comment: Me alegra que lo hayas resuelto, en cuanto al &_xxxxx por lo general es un numero para romper el cache del ajax, deberían de ser los milisegundos transcurridos desde el 1 de enero de 1970

Comment: Yo en mi caso detecte de que habia incluido dos veces bootstrap. Asi que removí la versión mas vieja y listo

Answer (score 1):

Tu primera línea de Javascript es incorrecta:

```
$(document).ready(funcion1());
```

debería ser:

```
$(document).ready(funcion1);
```

Y, además, JQuery recomienda a día de hoy escribirlo así (el resultado es el mismo, pero queda más sencillo):

```
$(funcion1);
```

Explicación: Lo que quieres pasarle a la función `$.ready()` es una función, para que esta sea ejecutada. Pero si escribes `ready(funcion1());`, lo que estás haciendo es ejecutar `funcion1`y pasar el resultado a `ready()`, con lo que en realidad la función se está ejecutando antes de tiempo.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, compañero. Aún así, me sigue funcionando sólo la primera vez que compilo el proyecto y abro la subpágina. Una vez salgo a otra e intento volver a acceder a la anterior ha dejado de funcionar el script. Es como si la caché recargara la tabla sin recoger los datos del DOM y JQuery no pudiera sacar los valores del Controlador. El error es un "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404".

Comment: 404 es que la URL es incorrecta: puedes añadir la URL que falla en la pregunta?

Comment: En el Controller de la página tengo un modelo que crea un archivo Json con una lista con todos los valores recogidos de las BBDD para luego ser utilizado en las vistas para crear una tabla con Foreach. El link en cuestión que da error es la llamada de JQuery al archivo Json (en este caso GetValues). El link no debería cambiar por lo que si estuviera erróneo no debería funcionar ni la primera vez, lo extraño es que falle después. PD: Me he dado cuenta que haciendo Ctrl+F5 la página sigue cargando el script y funciona, es sólo cuando cambio a otra y luego quiero volver a la primera.